# Looping through a table in a nested query in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, nested

I have a task where I have to identify the company database tables last_user_update and then store that in a separate table where reports for each tables last update can be monitored. What I'm aiming to do is have my query loop through a list of table names and so far I have the following:

1. Identify the all tables in the database:

   ```
     INSERT INTO [CorpDB1].[dbo].[tblTableNames]
      ([name])
      SELECT *
      FROM sys.Tables
      ORDER by name
   ```

The result is a table containing a 984 rows of table names for all tables in the DB.

Next I have the following:

2. Query to return and insert last_user_update into a new table called DatabaseTableHistory:

   ```
    INSERT INTO [CorpDB1].[dbo].[DatabaseTableHistory]
          ([DatabaseName]
          ,[last_user_update]
          ,[database_id]
          ,[object_id]
          ,[index_id]
          ,[user_seeks]
          ,[user_scans]
          ,[user_lookups]
          ,[user_updates]
          ,[last_user_seek])

    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,    
    database_id, object_id, index_id, user_seeks, user_scans, user_lookups, 
    user_updates, last_user_seek
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'CorpDB1')
    AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('tblStatesList')  AND last_user_update <     
    '20150430'
   ```

This query works as designed. What I'm trying to do is have the last query loop through the table containing the list of table names inserting it where OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('tbleStatesList') is so I don't have to manually run the query by typing each table name in by hand. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, apart from being wrong (`SELECT *` will return much more than just `name`), your first query is completely unnecessary. There's no need to select your table names into a cache table.

You can get the list of tables you need by using an `INNER JOIN` between `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and `sys.tables` on the `object_id`.

I'm assuming you want all the indexes on CorpDB1 tables that have a `last_user_update` prior to 30th April 2015.

```
USE CorpDB1;
GO

INSERT INTO [CorpDB1].[dbo].[DatabaseTableHistory]
       ([DatabaseName]
       ,[last_user_update]
       ,[database_id]
       ,[object_id]
       ,[index_id]
       ,[user_seeks]
       ,[user_scans]
       ,[user_lookups]
       ,[user_updates]
       ,[last_user_seek])

 SELECT 
  DB_NAME(ddius.database_id) AS DatabaseName, -- Fix this on your query
  ddius.last_user_update,    
  ddius.database_id, 
  ddius.object_id, 
  ddius.index_id, 
  ddius.user_seeks, 
  ddius.user_scans, 
  ddius.user_lookups, 
  ddius.user_updates, 
  ddius.last_user_seek
 FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ddius
 INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON t.object_id = ddius.object_id
 WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'CorpDB1')
   AND last_user_update < '20150430';
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. On the first line of your select, does one have to use the database_ID or can you use database name?

Comment: You can hard code the Database name if you want `'CorpDB1' AS DatabaseName,`. Or you can just use the `DB_NAME()` function, e.g. `DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName`. Yours was using the `OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)` function, which would get the table name, rather than database name

Comment: What am I missing. I'm getting 0 row(s) affected. Also in looking at the query, why would you store database name since the goal is to store the above information for each table in the DB?

Comment: Remove the `last_user_update` part of the `WHERE` clause and add it to the columns you're selecting to check the values. It's quite often `NULL` if it's never been updated, so you'll possibly need to include all NULLs in the result set as well as `< '20150430'`

Comment: No problem! Shout if you need anything else.

Comment: Just one last thing I think: So everything inserts into the table very nicely. Its just showing the data for the DB as a whole. How can I modify the query to spit out those values for all 980 something tables in my DB?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76655/discussion-between-alex-and-mark-sinkinson).

Comment: Sure, just let me know what you want as I'm not sure I understand what you think you're missing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with MSSQL, I would suggest creating a stored procedure to loop through the first dataset using a cursor.

See the link below for a short tutorial on how to create and user cursors for this purpose.

http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/

Comment: I don't see any sane reason to use a CURSOR here.

Comment: While the 'sanity' of my answer may be debatable, the use of a cursor to loop over a returned dataset for the purposes of dynamically generating an executable SQL statement is perfectly acceptable to the database.  You can't join the tables because the tablename is being used as a parameter of a custom function named OBJECT_ID().

Comment: Based on the initial requirements, there is absolutely no need for a cursor. `OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('tblStatesList')` (where `tblStatesList` is a table name from `tblTableNames`) is redundant if you join between `sys.tables` and `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` on `object_id`. Why overcomplicate a simple JOIN?